# Ayuda con .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Tengo este código para hacer url friendly

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ / [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-z_0-9,\/]*)/?$ index.php [nc,l]

</IfModule>
```

Hasta ahora en un servidor privado iba sin problemas, pero ahora he migrado el servidor a 1&1 y no funciona ese código.

¿que estoy haciendo mal? El error que da es 404 página no encontrada

Comment: ¿Has revisado si el apache tiene el mod_rewrite habilitado?

Comment: ¿Seguro que el nuevo servidor está tomando el .htaccess?

Comment: Esta súper limitado 1&1 y no puedo tocar la configuración más allá de seleccionar la versión de Php. pero entiendo que si, porque prestashop lo usa y no falla. @fredyfx

Comment: Si elimino el htaccess si veo la pagina, solo que no puedo navegar por ella ya que no funcionan los enlaces. @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: "Súper limitado" en lo personal, prefiero tener control total de root para tener plena libertad en las configuraciones, te recomiendo usar https://linode.com o https://digitalocean.com que cuentan con un plan inicial de 5$ al mes. Si deseas configurar un panel de administración tipo CPanel, esta es una gran opción: https://www.webmin.com/